# EMF transmission from cell phone's battery

Tags: rf, frequency, electromagnetism, cellphone, batteries

According to [Cell Phones & Wi-Fi―Are Children, Fetuses and Fertility at Risk?](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2013/09/21/cell-phone-wifi-radiation.aspx)

> While one can put the phone in ‘airplane mode,’ which disconnects it from Wi-Fi and the Internet, the cell phone still emits magnetic fields from the battery, shown to have equally important biologically consequences, including links to childhood asthma and obesity from fetal exposures.

Is ELF the magnetic fields it is referring to? If that is so, 
how many mG or μT are considered to have health effects (if any) or 
is a cell phone's or tablet's battery's magnetic field transmission too low to be considered?

Comment: You do realize that that is not an actual site with medical information, but a bullshit site selling bullshit handwavy newage crap? Anyway, about your technical question: if they even know what they're talking about, it's plausible they are talking about magnetic fields caused by flowing charge (i.e. an electrical circuit). You can calculate ballpark estimates using the Biot-Savart law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law

Comment: Also worth noting that the magnetic field created by the standby current draw on the battery is much weaker than an ordinary refrigerator magnet (does your phone stick to the fridge?), and some of those very same new-age crap sites sell magnets for healing. Maybe only very weak magnetic fields are harmful? Having a hard time reconciling this with homeopathy...OH JEEZ MY BELIEF SYSTEM IS SELF-CONTRADICTORY! NOOOO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That article you linked seems to be of an unqualified source, note that the same "Dr. Mercola" who wrote this is also active in other contra-scientific movements like "vaccines cause autism", "GMOs are evil", "flouride kills you in 1000 different ways" and similar.

Now, disregarding the opinion of this "Dr. Mercola", please consider that there *are* government regulations regarding ELF. Exposure to very strong electromagnetic waves *can* damage body tissue, *but* for that to occur, the waves need to be pretty strong, way stronger than your tablet/cellphone could ever generate.
For instance, in regards to induction stoves, the Swiss government recommends a distance of at least 30 cm to your cooking surface for most of the time. But keep in mind that these stoves are *built* to create strong electromagnetic fields, strong enough to get ferromagnetic materials hot. So basically, if the electromagnetic waves of the phone are not enough to cook inductively with (they aren't), your child should be safe with less than 30 cm of distance to the phone.

Also note the statement of the WHO that "to date, no adverse health effects have been established as being caused by mobile phone use."
So basically, your children are safe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the battery per se that would be emitting electromagnetic fields.  If there were no load on the battery (no circuitry attached) then no electrical current would be flowing and no field would be generated.  The battery is there to store energy, not emit radiation, then to the extent current flows from the battery to power a circuit, some of that energy may be radiated, deliberately or not.

Of course, cellphones exist to emit electromagnetic radiation.  That's how they communicate to the cell tower, WiFi access point, Bluetooth device, or NFC reader, plus the unintentional but unavoidable EMI (electromagnetic interference) that radiates from any circuit where current is flowing.  The deliberate radiation is generally high frequency, 700MHz to 5GHz carrier, many orders of magnitude different from ELF (extremely low frequency) at less than 30 Hz.  The unintentional radiation may span a wider range of frequencies but will be far lower in magnitude.

The question may be confusing the type of radiation typical of power lines with that of cellphones.  There have been public health concerns raised about the effects of both, but they are not necessarily the same issue due to the difference in operating frequency.  There's also a huge difference between living next to a high voltage power transformer or cellular tower, and using a phone or power drill.

The government regulates how much radiation may come from any given device, both deliberately and not.  As this forum is for electrical designers, most people here would be concerned with designing products to stay within those constraints while performing well.  Some may have read up on health effects but we are not biology researchers here.  Perhaps a search for relevant research papers would turn up the type of information you're looking for.

References:
[Wikipedia (ELF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency)
[National Institutes of Health (search: electromagnetic fields)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=electromagnetic%20fields)